# Left-Click Drag Select in 3.5

Tags: 3d-view, interface, settings

I recently installed Blender 3.5.1, upgrading from 3.4.1, and I've noticed an odd change in how the left click select works when you have a different tool selected. In 3.4.1 (and previous versions), when any tool other than box, circle, or lasso select was active (cursor notwithstanding), left click dragging (I've have right click select set since 2.x) off of the gizmo would always use the most recently active select tool. So far, I have tried to adjust the drag behaviour in the Active Tool tab of the Tool tab in viewport mode, imported my keybinds from 3.4.1, and tried looking into the preferences menu Am I missing something obvious? Is this a bug that I should report to Blender?